# Issue while restarting the Tomcat server

Tags: bash, tomcat, sh

I am using `apache-tomcat-8.5.15` and starting(`startup.sh`) & stopping(`shutdown.sh`) it using the shell scripts contained in its `bin/` directory. In my custom shell script file, when I write:

```
./shutdown.sh
./startup.sh
```

and run, it seems to work fine. But when I run with

```
./shutdown.sh && ./startup.sh
```

it shows

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

saying that the address is already bound.

Why is this happening? How can I resolve this error?

Or, is there a simple command that can restart tomcat?

Comment: Either `shutdown.sh` isn't shutting down your instance cleanly or you need to wait for a few seconds before calling `startup.sh`.  Try `./shutdown.sh && sleep 5 && ./startup.sh`.

Comment: I guess `shutdown.sh` is somewhat async and continues to do something after returning to the terminal. Just sleep a bit after it finished

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured out on my own. I'll post my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why is this happening? How can I resolve this error?

It wasn't a issue of whether having `&&` or not. It was just a testing mistake.

It was because

```
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [38,251] milliseconds.
```

This part was eating up almost 40 secs so that when I was testing the script with `&&`, the `shutdown.sh` couldn't shut down the tomcat process since it was on its initialization stage.

To fix this, you could set in `JAVA_OPT` to feed `dev/urandom`. Refer to [this answer & comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36610855/3535760) for the detailed solution.

In fact, without this problem, it was fine to do either way.

---

#### Is there a simple command that can restart tomcat?

Probably not.

---

#### Are `starup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` run asynchronously?

I don't have a definite answer on this, but according to the code inside scripts([here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/bin/startup.sh) and [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/bin/catalina.sh)) which is same as in my version of Tomcat, they don't seem to be async. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Why is this happening? How can I resolve this error?**

This problem occurs mainly when you try to run your tomcat on a port which is already being used by other application or other process of tomcat itself,

Yes, you can surly resolve this by either just killing or stopping the process which is bind to that port.

Comment: I know what the error message means. My question wasn't about that.