# Very long startup - GraphDB 8.7.2

Tags: graphdb

When starting up graphdb, the log reports a few warnings related to an illegal reflective access operation by `org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils` in `lib/spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar` and then pauses for a wile at:

```
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:34,109 [main | c.o.g.Config] Using 'file:/home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2/conf/logback.xml' as logback's configuration file for graphdb
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:34,427 [main | c.o.g.s.GraphDB] Starting GraphDB in workbench mode.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2/lib/spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:39,572 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Home directory: /home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:39,572 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Config directory: /home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2/conf
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:39,573 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Data directory: /home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2/data
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:39,573 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Work directory: /home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2/work
[INFO ] 2018-11-19 17:02:39,573 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Logs directory: /home/ubuntu/graphdb-free-8.7.2/logs
```

After approximately 8-13 minutes, the log reports a session ID generation process is finished and the server is deployed:

```
[WARN ] 2018-11-19 16:38:41,843 [main | o.a.c.u.SessionIdGeneratorBase] Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [784,201] milliseconds.
```

Running:

- graphdb-free-8.7.2
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17, OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3), OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3, mixed mode)

Is it necessary for it to take so much time? Or, can this be turned off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely ignore the first warning message caused by running the database with Java 9. The new module encapsulation system causes this warning. See [what is an illegal reflective access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access).

For some unknown reasons, the Apache Tomcat 9.0.4 code base is not capable to generate a random ID. Like it's suggested in [Slow startup on Tomcat 7.0.57 because of SecureRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201794/slow-startup-on-tomcat-7-0-57-because-of-securerandom) you should start the database with `./graphdb -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` or simply add to `$GDB_HOME/bin/graphdb.in.sh` the line: `JAVA_OPTS_ARRAY+=("-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom")`.