# What exactly does "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" do when containerizing a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-security, dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The above `Dockerfile` sample is from the official [Spring Boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) for docker. I would like to know what the security property is used for since I don't usually set that up when running the app on my local development environment but it seems to come up on various containerization guides. Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The purpose of that security property is to speed up tomcat startup. By default the library used to generate random number in JVM on Unix systems relies on `/dev/random`. On docker containers there isn't enough entropy to support `/dev/random`. See [Not enough entropy to support `/dev/random` in docker containers running in boot2docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26021181/8482479).
The random number generator is used for session ID generation. Changing it to `/dev/urandom` will make the startup process faster.

Similar question [Slow startup on Tomcat 7.0.57 because of SecureRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28201794/8482479)

Comment: Is it actual in case with Spring Web Flux and Netty?

Comment: @Denis.E I am not entirely sure but it seems that Netty has similar issues [#3419](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3419). 
The difference is that netty times out after 3 seconds and use a hard-coded random number if the seed uniquifier cannot be initialized. See [ThreadLocalRandom](https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/util/internal/ThreadLocalRandom.html)

Answer (score 2):

From Java 9 through Java 11 (LTS), this option is to increase the entropy of random numbers generated by the **java.security.SecureRandom** class whilst avoiding the risk of having the code blocked unexpectedly. It configures the JVM:

1. To seed the **SecureRandom** class using the `/dev/urandom` special
   file on Unix-like  OSes to avoid having the code unexpectedly
   blocked due to lack of entropy.
2. To use the *Deterministic Random Bit Generator (DRBG)* mechanisms
   described in [NIST 800-90Ar1](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final). These mechanisms implement modern
          algorithms as strong as SHA-512 and AES-256.

Comment: According to the JDK 8 Security Enhancements official Oracle document, the /dev/./urandom workaround is no more necessary from JDK 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html But this answer says java 9 through 11, so I was wondering if it is still useful ?

Comment: The extra `/./` sets the strongest SecureRandom implementation available (DRBG in Java 11) to be used regardless the underpinning platform. `urandom` avoids getting the code blocked unexpectedly.